# How to run android app using eclipse

Tags: android

I am using the OS as Windows 7. In which I want to run my Android app through the Eclipse.
so I connect my android device to my laptop through USB connector. In my device shown as " USB connected ", but when I click the run configuration to select the device, the device id never shown/displayed. and I was tried in the CMD prompt mode, by Killing and start ADB server, but it never worked. Could you anyone provide the solution.

Comment: 2 suggestions: Install Kies and check Developer Debug mode in settings as TRUE

Comment: YOU NEED TO INSTALL APPROPRIATE ADB DRIVERS ON WINDOWS.

Comment: I got it working through this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-debugging-on-real-device/

Comment: Thanks a lot ThePCWizard.. its working fine. Now I can connect the device in my windows system.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that USB debugging is enabled. To do that go to your phone and find "Developer Options", for me it is Settings->System->Developer Options. If the device doesn't show up in Eclipse after that, make sure the ADB is running, and that it can recognize your device.

Answer (score 0):

If a device doesn't appear in the list when you use a command like "adb list", probably there is some issue with device drivers.
But if you think device drivers are installed .. just try restarting the device..

Answer (score 0):

Enable USB debugging in your phone settings: Apps -> Development -> USB Debugging.